# MediaCenter with through put of 20MB/s

Tags: nas

I am trying to create a NAS but I want to run my own software on it. I want to be able to download data around 20MB/s over WiFi from the system.

I used a raspi and created a prototype, but as it uses a single bus it is not able to transfer data from the HDD to the user at the rates I am talking about. Anybody know any build that suits this? Looking for suggestions.

1. Budget – around USD 300 - 400
2. Size requirements – as small as possible
3. Operating conditions – Will be deployed in my van: take impacts into consideration, I am planning to devise a case that can solve this issue.  Needs heat dissipation solution as my van is not air conditioned.
4. Desired software you want to run on it – web server running on Node.JS
5. Storage media – 2TB HDD (as of now I use a 1TB external)
6. Power solution – need a powerbackup that can last for one hour
7. I need good network adapters and USB ports that won't hinder my data streaming.
8. Dust proof as I am installing this in India where dust and temperature are a common phenomena
9. I don't need a screen.

I want the case to be smaller in size, I am willing to fabricate one myself if its needed to address my needs.

Comment: I wish to run my own webserver for the interface

Comment: I'm closing this question because it's asking for a full custom build, whereas questions that work on this site ask for a single piece of hardware. The bounty you placed on this question has been refunded.

Comment: It looks to me like the OP is asking for a single piece of hardware once it's all put together - a custom NAS. Alpha3031 has answered usefully with a custom build in the past (http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/224/mini-pc-with-dual-quad-core-cpu-as-mac-mini-alternative/885#885) If we cut ourselves out of build recommendations we will have eliminated much of our usefulness.

Comment: @55597, If you have a concern about a particular moderation action, please post on [meta](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you are looking for what I think you are looking for I would suggest you look for a cheap server on ebay or in a small form factor case for around 80$ like this one:http://www.ebay.com/itm/FAST-DELL-DUAL-CORE-3-4-GHZ-DESKTOP-COMPUTER-PC-4GB-RAM-Wifi-WINDOWS-7-PRO-/262152856157?hash=item3d0987225d:g:AdoAAOSwYmZXI2bs

This is very small comes with windows 7 and you can configure it with a 2tb hard drive for 100$ then for an os you can use windows 7 or you can use free nas which is an amazing server software which I have used myself and if you want to bring the 80$ down you can look for one with no os and just buy the hard drive and slip it in and put free nas on it. Now I dont know if you need a nice router but if you do I suggest this: [http://www.officedepot.com/a/products/555607/Belkin-N300-Wireless-Router/?cm_mmc=PLA-*-Google-*-Printers_Scanners_Faxes-_-555607-VQ6-47886868676-VQ16-c-VQ17-pla-VQ18-online-VQ19-555607-VQ20-76926630596-VQ21--VQ22-177839036-VQ27-9203161796&gclid=CILM5pvuh84CFQ6EaQodFvsHxw](http://www.officedepot.com/a/products/555607/Belkin-N300-Wireless-Router/?cm_mmc=PLA-_-Google-_-Printers_Scanners_Faxes-_-555607-VQ6-47886868676-VQ16-c-VQ17-pla-VQ18-online-VQ19-555607-VQ20-76926630596-VQ21--VQ22-177839036-VQ27-9203161796&gclid=CILM5pvuh84CFQ6EaQodFvsHxw)

I have this hooked up to my modem and can get around 100mbps download speed

Speaking of modems if you want a nice one of those I would suggest this: ARRIS / Motorola SurfBoard SB6183 DOCSIS 3.0 Cable Modem – 600 MHz Dual-Thread Processor

If you have decent internet speed any one of these things are nice options for what you want if I am reading it right Sorry If I did not understand what you wanted

btw for freenas there are TONS of easy tutorials to set it up

But I have no idea if I wrote what you wanted sorry if I did not

Answer (score 0):

OK, third attempt is the charm, right? This gets you what you want in what has to be, bar none, the smallest possible package. But it will require some know-how on your end as far as software goes.

```
PCPartPicker part list: http://pcpartpicker.com/list/CHG7WX
Price breakdown by merchant: http://pcpartpicker.com/list/CHG7WX/by_merchant/

Case Fan: Thermaltake A1888 47.3 CFM  80mm Fan  ($12.99 @ SuperBiiz) 
External Storage: Western Digital Elements 2TB External Hard Drive  ($83.86 @ Amazon) 
UPS: APC BE450G-CN UPS  ($39.78 @ Amazon) 
Other: Linksys AC1900 Dual Band SMART Wi-Fi Gigabit Router (EA6900) ($99.99)
Total: $236.62
Prices include shipping, taxes, and discounts when available
Generated by PCPartPicker 2016-07-21 12:57 EDT-0400
```

Here's how this setup works:

1. The Router acts as the wireless server, running OpenWRT or dd-WRT.
2. The External HDD connects to the router's 3.0 port
3. The fan connects to the router's 2.0 port and is set to cool the router - you may want to drill holes in the router's shell to facilitate this.
4. The UPS powers the whole setup.

Here's the trick - how to get node.js running on a router? I think I have the answer:

1. Install OpenWRT or dd-WRT on the router, whichever works for you. This model supports both options.
2. On a desktop computer - preferably a very powerful linux workstation - you [crosscompile node.js for ARMv7](https://gist.github.com/Gioyik/7895192) (the chip powering this router is specifically noted [here](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/linksys/wrt1x00ac_series)).
3. Copy the resulting script file over to your router's flash storage area - you have ~100mb NAND flash to work with.
4. Install [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).
5. Run the script inside a detached tmux or screen session on the router.
6. Configure router as needed to make server visible to connecting parties.
7. Don't go over ~400mb RAM usage, your router only has 512mb.